# sed pattern match until first match only

Tags: linux, unix, sed, pattern-matching, ksh

I am struggling with a sed regex. 
I looked at the older existing threads on this topic but couldn't figure out the solution and I would like to avoid using awk command.

I want the capture the part of an input string before the first timestamp in the string.

Case 1:

```
$ input_str=abc_123_def_20181217T2345
$ echo $input_str | sed 's/\(.*\)_\([0-9]\{8\}\).*/\1/'
$ abc_123_def
```

Case 2:

```
$ input_str=abc_123_def_20181217T2345_20181218T2345
$ echo $input_str | sed 's/\(.*\)_\([0-9]\{8\}\).*/\1/'
$ abc_123_def_20181217T2345
```

Expected output: abc_123_def

As can be seen in Case 2, the sed expression is capturing the first timestamp also. I understand that `.*` will match as much as possible, but how do I get around it?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like `sed 's/_[0-9]\{8\}.*//' <<< "$input_str"` will be enough. See https://ideone.com/xMECWM

Comment: Thanks!! That worked. So your logic is to basically just replace the timestamps right?

Comment: See [my explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53813088/3832970).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may match the first timestamp after `_` and then match all to the end of the line to remove the match:

```
sed 's/_[0-9]\{8\}.*//' <<< "$input_str"
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/xMECWM)

This way, you leverage the fact that the regex engine searches the string from left to right, and the `_[0-9]\{8\}` will match the *first* occurrence of timestamp *from the left*, and the `.*` will match the rest of the line, and since it is the `s` command, it will remove the found match leaving you with the substring before the first TIMESTAMP occurrence.

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you so much!